# Grid of products

Tags: mysql, database-design, entity-attribute-value

how I modeling a grid of products in data base?

Products grid is the situation where a product may have variations, or additional attributes.

ex: shirt with color, size etc.

without grid:

```
COD 1 - shirt x color red size P - 2 amount
COD 2 - shirt x color red size M - 3 amount

COD 1 - shirt x
subcod 1 - color red size P - 2 amount
subcod 2 - color red size M - 3 amount
```

I thought in some situations, but all are costly

Comment: How many total product attributes do you expect?  If this number be small, and you don't reasonably expect the number to grow large, then you might get away with just adding columns for each attribute.

Comment: Read other questions tagged "entity-attribute-value".